# unfortunately your has stopped working

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple number guessing game in android. A random number is generated when the app in launched and the user has to guess the number. The result is displayed in the form of a long toast. But when I run the app and try and enter a number the emulator says: "unfortunately High Low Game has stopped working". I have tried resetting the app and also clearing data from my emulators settings menu but it didn't make a difference. I sense something is wrong with my java code but haven't been able to figure out what is the problem so far.

Here is the java code:

```
    package com.example.pooria.hilowgame;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.util.Random;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int randomNum;

    public void buttonClicked(View view){
        EditText numField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.numField);
        int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.toString());

        String toastMessage= "";
        if(numFieldVal>randomNum){
            toastMessage= "Higher";
        }else if(numFieldVal==randomNum){
            toastMessage= "You made the right guess!!!";
        }else{
            toastMessage= "Lower";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toastMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random randomGenerator= new Random();
        int randomNum= randomGenerator.nextInt(101);
    }
}
```

and the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pooria.hilowgame.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Guess the random number"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Guess!!!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/numField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

Thanks
```

Comment: Add logcat to your question

Comment: numField.getText().toString()

Comment: There can be many reasons of this crash. Kindly post your logcat. Apparently, you should change numField.toString() to numField.getText().toString().trim(). trim() is very important as if there is any space, it'll not be parsed to int

Comment: Change ```int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.toString());``` Line to ```int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.getText().toString());```. It will work

Comment: Well, you already got your answer above^. Also, get rid of `int` in the line `int randomNum= randomGenerator.nextInt(101);` in the `onCreate()` since, `randomNum` is your instance variable and you don'r need to redeclare it.

Comment: ...  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1552/logging-and-using-logcat/14718/using-the-logcat#t=201608280823023498773

Comment: Strangely I'm the only one to downvote and flag..

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.pooria.hilowgame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Random;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int randomNum; <--------

public void buttonClicked(View view){
    EditText numField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.numField);
    int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.getText().toString()); <-------

    String toastMessage= "";
    if(numFieldVal>randomNum){
        toastMessage= "Higher";
    }else if(numFieldVal==randomNum){
        toastMessage= "You made the right guess!!!";
    }else{
        toastMessage= "Lower";
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toastMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random randomGenerator= new Random();
    randomNum = randomGenerator.nextInt(101); <--------
}
}
```

See the marked lines. Code is changed to the correct, but I added text to explain what is wrong.

Change

`int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.toString());`

to

`int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.getText().toString());`

The unchanged line is the cause of the crash.

And for a game related problem:

This line:

```
int randomNum = randomGenerator.nextInt(101);
```

is wrong. You create a new local variable, meaning the global randomNum is 0 - always. The solution is simple - remove the int, so it references the main randomNum variable.

And by doing that, you have solved unwanted results and solved the crash.

Comment: Read the comments in the question

Comment: I did and I still belive it is not the cause

Comment: `int numFieldVal= Integer.parseInt(numField.toString());`...right here: `NumberFormatException` mainly because `numField.toString()` will return the mem location of the allocated edittext.

Comment: randomNum is null, NullPointerException right there

Comment: Why don't we stop guessing the issue untill the logcat comes up and we'll see who is right

Comment: No guesses here @Polarbear0106 the code makes it quite clear what is going wrong

Comment: NOPE...You see, primitive instance vars have default values (`0` for int, `false` for boolean, etc.) So, the correction you mentioned won't save him from the crash although, it would save him from undesired results.

Comment: Forgot about that. Updated the answer.